# Match records in 2 mutually distinct tables based on multiple criteria using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to build a data set for a study where I have members divided into 2 groups, let's call them the Hatfields and McCoys. There are more Hatfields than McCoys, and I want to match each Hatfield with someone I define as similar enough in the McCoys. I want all the matches to be 1-1. Each Hatfield should match to 1 McCoy, and no McCoy should be matched more than once. There are likely to be some multiple matches, but I want to eliminate those. I'm not picky about the "best" match, just that it's a match.

Member  Date    Score

A   2/1/2014    1.00

B   4/4/2014    1.50

C   9/15/2014   1.00

Member  Start_Date  End_Date    Score

D   1/1/2014    12/31/2014  1.00

E   6/1/2014    12/31/2014  0.50

F   1/1/2014    5/31/2014   1.50

G   1/1/2014    12/31/2014  1.00

H   8/1/2014    12/31/2014  1.00

The table above shows an example (sorry for the poor formatting). I want to match each of ABC to one of DEFGH, and my criteria are that (1) the date for ABC falls between start and end dates in the 2nd table and (2) the scores match.

I'd thought about trying to sort each table then work my way down an index field. I could create an index field on each table, and then if the first record from the first table matches the 3rd record from the second, I would know that all future matches would have index_2 > 3. That would prevent anyone from getting reused.

I can't quite put it all together though.

Thanks for any help! I love learning SQL and appreciate new tricks!

Comment: ddl and sample sample data would make this a lot easier. sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

djm50,

I couldn't do it in one SQL Statement, this should give you what you are looking for.

'#MatchedRows' Contains all the fields for both tables that match the Selection Criteria. Inside the Cursor I am keeping track of the Members that have been used and it is the first time, I add the row# to the '#SelectedRows' table. The I do an inner join on MatchedRows and SelectedRows to get you what you want.

```
DECLARE @row_number INT
    ,@member1 VARCHAR(1)
    ,@member2 VARCHAR(1);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#UsedMember') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #UsedMember;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SelectedRows') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #SelectedRows;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MatchedRows') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #MatchedRows;

Create Table #UsedMember ( Member varchar(1) );
Create Table #SelectedRows ( rowId int );

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY T1.MEMBER
        ) AS Row
    ,T1.Member T1_Member
    ,T1.DATE T1_Date
    ,T1.Score T1_Score
    ,T2.[Member] [T2_Member]
    ,T2.[StartDate] [T2_StartDate]
    ,T2.[EndDate] [T2_EndDate]
    ,T2.[Score] [T2_Score]
INTO #MatchedRows
FROM TableABC T1
    ,TableDEFG T2
WHERE (
        T1.DATE BETWEEN T2.StartDate
            AND T2.EndDate
        )
    AND T1.Score = T2.Score


--  select * from #MatchedRows

DECLARE member_cursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT T1.Row AS Row
    ,T1.T1_Member AS Member1
    ,T1.T2_Member AS Member2
FROM #MatchedRows T1

OPEN member_cursor

FETCH NEXT
FROM member_cursor
INTO @row_number
    ,@member1
    ,@member2

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT '-';

    IF NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 'x'
            FROM #UsedMember
            WHERE #UsedMember.Member = @member1
                OR #UsedMember.Member = @member2
            )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #UsedMember (Member)
        VALUES (@member1);

        INSERT INTO #UsedMember (Member)
        VALUES (@member2);

        INSERT INTO #SelectedRows (rowId)
        VALUES (@row_number);
    END

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM member_cursor
    INTO @row_number
        ,@member1
        ,@member2
END

CLOSE member_cursor;

DEALLOCATE member_cursor;

SELECT *
FROM #MatchedRows
INNER JOIN #SelectedRows ON (#MatchedRows.Row = #SelectedRows.rowId)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I thought it probably had to use cursors, but I'm not good enough at SQL to do it freehand. I know enough about coding that I can adapt once I have the outline, so this should work perfectly.